# Got errors when running flutter test command

Tags: flutter

I use `flutter create testtest` to create a sample app called `testest` to run the sample test case, but it throw errors, when I run `flutter test ./test/widget_test.dart`

errors:

```
flutter test
00:00 +0 -1: loading /home/helen/Git/testtest/test/widget_test.dart [E]                            
Failed to load "Git/testtest/test/widget_test.dart":
Shell subprocess crashed with unexpected exit code 127 before connecting to test harness.
Test: Git/testtest/test/widget_test.dart
Shell: /home/h/flutter/bin/cache/artifacts/engine/linux-x64/flutter_tester


00:00 +0 -1: Some tests failed.                                                                    
Shell: /home/h/flutter/bin/cache/artifacts/engine/linux-  x64/flutter_tester: error while loading shared libraries: libGLU.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

**Test code**
        import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

```
 import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
 import 'package:testtest/main.dart';

 void main() {
    testWidgets('Counter increments smoke test', (WidgetTester tester) async {
     // Build our app and trigger a frame.
     await tester.pumpWidget(new MyApp());

    // Verify that our counter starts at 0.
    expect(find.text('0'), findsOneWidget);
    expect(find.text('1'), findsNothing);

    // Tap the '+' icon and trigger a frame.
    await tester.tap(find.byIcon(Icons.add));
    await tester.pump();

    // Verify that our counter has incremented.
    expect(find.text('0'), findsNothing);
    expect(find.text('1'), findsOneWidget);
 });
 }
```

**`flutter doctor`**

[✓] Flutter (on Linux, locale en_NZ.UTF-8, channel alpha)
    • Flutter at /home/helen/flutter
    • Framework revision 8f65fec5f5 (4 weeks ago), 2017-12-12 09:50:14 -0800
    • Engine revision edaecdc8b8
    • Tools Dart version 1.25.0-dev.11.0
    • Engine Dart version 2.0.0-edge.d8ae797298c3a6cf8dc9f4558707bd2672224d3e

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 26.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /home/helen/Android/Sdk
    • Android NDK at /home/helen/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle
    • Platform android-26, build-tools 26.0.3
    • Java binary at: /home/helen/sdks/android-studio/jre/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-915-b01)

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.0)
    • Android Studio at /home/helen/sdks/android-studio
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-915-b01)

[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2017.2)
    • Flutter plugin version 18.4
    • Dart plugin version 172.4343.25

[-] Connected devices
    • None

**Solution:**
I'm using `fedora` and to to solve this problem, run the command: 
`sudo dnf install mesa-libGLU.x86_64`

Comment: Does `flutter doctor` report any errors?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer : `flutter doctor` seems fine to me

Answer (score 1):

looks something related to `libGLU`...

```
Shell: /home/h/flutter/bin/cache/artifacts/engine/linux-  x64/flutter_tester: error while loading shared libraries: libGLU.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

check if you have the correct packet installed. If not:

```
## UBUNTU-LIKE ##
sudo apt-get install libglu1
## Fedora ##
dnf install mesa-libGLU.x86_64
```

or

```
## UBUNTU-LIKE ##
sudo apt-get install libglu1-mesa:i386
## Fedora ##
dnf install mesa-libGLU.i686
```

depending if you might need the 32bits version

Comment: it throws error when trying to install either `libglu1` or `libglu1-mesa:i386`.
 Error: `sudo dnf install libglu1
Last metadata expiration check: 0:10:41 ago on Wed 10 Jan 2018 09:06:06 NZDT.
No match for argument: libglu1`

Comment: by the way, I'm using fedora

Comment: I edited to add the solution. It was so close, I guessed your system had installed the 64-bit already...

Comment: I'm not sure if this command `dnf install mesa-libGLU.i686` would solve the issue, but 1 upvote for your effort :) thanks again